# XML select with multiple namespaces when not a url

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

Wonder if anyone can help, looked at other posts but they seem to have a URL in namespace whereas output from 3rd party I get does not.
Not come across an XML structured like this before;

```
<xml xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
<s:ElementType rs:updatable="true" content="eltOnly" name="row">
<s:AttributeType rs:name="Application Name" name="c0" rs:write="true" rs:number="1">
<s:datatype rs:precision="0" dt:maxLength="62" dt:type="string"/>
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType rs:name="Application ID" name="c1" rs:write="true" rs:number="2">
<s:datatype rs:precision="0" dt:maxLength="4" dt:type="int" rs:fixedlength="true"/>
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType rs:name="Site Name" name="c2" rs:write="true" rs:number="3">
<s:datatype rs:precision="0" dt:maxLength="42" dt:type="string"/>
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="TemplateID" rs:write="true" rs:number="4">
<s:datatype rs:precision="0" dt:maxLength="4" dt:type="int" rs:fixedlength="true"/>
</s:AttributeType>
<s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<rs:insert>
<z:row TemplateID="3" c2="HostName" c1="1" c0="Master_Script"/>
<z:row TemplateID="3" c2="HostName" c1="2" c0="Network_Script"/>
<z:row TemplateID="3" c2="HostName" c1="3" c0="ACD_DN_App"/>
<z:row TemplateID="3" c2="HostName" c1="4" c0="NACD_DN_App"/>
</rs:insert>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

and I am trying to get the **z:row** entries in a SelectNodes to get the **c1** and **c0** attributes.

Tried below after looking at other posts but not getting anywhere fast.
I do notice the XML namespaces are not traditional URLs, not sure impact that has or whether should be treated differently?

```
    appXML.LoadXml(wsResponse);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(appXML.NameTable);
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("rs", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset");
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");
    XmlNOdeList xmlRows = appXML.SelectNodes("/rs:data/rs:insert/z:row",nsMgr);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be double slash on the start of the rs? `//rs:data/rs:insert/z:row`

Comment: Then you can get the value of the attributes using `xmlRows[index].Attributes["c0"].Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML namespaces not being a URL doesn't matter. You are doing `SelectNodes` from the XML document level (`appXML`), so you need to mention the root element in the XPath, for example:

```
XmlNodeList xmlRows = appXML.SelectNodes("/xml/rs:data/rs:insert/z:row",nsMgr);
foreach(XmlElement row in xmlRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.Attributes["c0"].Value);
}
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/46ijvy)</kbd>**

Or you can do `SelectNodes` from the root element level (notice that `/` at the beginning of XPath expression always refer to the document, so we need to omit it to make the XPath starts from the root element `appXML.DocumentElement`):

```
XmlNodeList xmlRows = appXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("rs:data/rs:insert/z:row",nsMgr);
```

Or you can start the XPath with *descendant-or-self* axis instead of the default *child* axis:

```
XmlNodeList xmlRows = appXML.SelectNodes("//rs:data/rs:insert/z:row",nsMgr);
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that //. I guess I was getting tunnel vision on the namespace side of it.